# How to loop every minute until API response condition is true?

Tags: powershell, loops, rest, scripting

I just recently started on writing Powershell scripts. I have a project where I'm performing Load Tests. I Run the test and Generate a Report based on the result of the test. The tool I am using does that all through their API's. So I have 3 Rest API's that I am sending calls using Powershell script.

**1st call: Starts a Load Testing for however many iteration is setup in the configuration (Maybe it runs for hours):**

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $StartTestUrl -ContentType "application/json" -OutVariable StartTestResponse -Body $StartTestRequestBody | ConvertTo-Json
```

**2nd call: Gets status of the Load Test we just ran/or still running:**

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $GetStatusUrl -ContentType "application/json" -OutVariable GetStatusResponse -Body $GetStatusRequestBody | ConvertTo-Json
```

**3rd call: Generate Report From the finished Test Run:**

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $GenerateReportUrl -ContentType "application/json" -OutVariable GenerateReportResponse -Body $GenerateReportRequestBody | ConvertTo-Json
```

**Goal:** I want to able to write a DO-WHILE loop or other loops in Powershell that checks the status of the test by calling 2nd api every minute for the status "DONE" in the response. And then start the 3rd call, because if the test is not DONE, I cannot generate a report.

**Example:**

```
foreach(var minute in minutes)
{

    // if(status.Done)
    // {
    //   CALL GenerateReport
    // }
    // else
    //{
        //keep checking every minute 
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using a do-while loop. In this example, it's assumed that the `$GetStatusResponse` is just a `$true`/`$false` value. In reality you will need to modify the code to check for the actual "DONE" message.

```
#1
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $StartTestUrl -ContentType "application/json" -OutVariable StartTestResponse -Body $StartTestRequestBody | ConvertTo-Json

do{
    # 2
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $GetStatusUrl -ContentType "application/json" -OutVariable GetStatusResponse -Body $GetStatusRequestBody | ConvertTo-Json

    if($GetStatusResponse -eq $False){
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    }

}while($GetStatusResponse -eq $False)

# 3
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $GenerateReportUrl -ContentType "application/json" -OutVariable GenerateReportResponse -Body $GenerateReportRequestBody | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Will this keep running for every minute until we get a True response from $GetStatusResponse?

Comment: @Hashim77 Yes. For the 2nd call. The condition `$GetStatusResponse -eq $False` is simplified; you will probably have to modify it to fit your code.

Comment: Right, once the 2nd call is called I get a response as such: {
    "d":  {
              "ApiKey":  "#####",
              "Status":  "DONE"
          }
}

Comment: If it is not DONE, I need to re-check after 1 minute. So I assume, I need to extract the Status from response body and check it like while($GetStatusResponse.Status eq "Done")?

Comment: @Hashim77 Exactly! Except you want `-ne`, as in "keep running while status is NOT Done".

Answer (score -1):

Start-sleep -seconds 60

will pause execution for 1 minute

[MS link to cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-5.1)